# Unable to install new version of libpng12.so.0 Ubuntu 20

Tags: apt, dpkg, libpng

I have Ubuntu 20. I installed libqtcore4:i386 to use packet tracer. When I installed a lot of unmet dependencies appear.

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libpng12-0:i386 (>= 1.2.13-4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` this error appear.

```
The following additional packages will be installed:

  libpng12-0:i386

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  libpng12-0:i386

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.

66 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/118 kB of archives.
After this operation, 315 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

(Reading database ... 231507 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...

Unpacking libpng12-0:i386 (1.2.50-1ubuntu2) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu
2_i386.deb (--unpack):

unable to install new version of '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0': No such file or directory

No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your release. The closest is Ubuntu Core 20 as specialist *snap* based releases use the *yy* format, unlike *yy.mm* used by server & desktops releases, but your question seems to be more a standard *yy.mm* release not a *yy* release.  (`apt` is a tool usually used by *yy.mm* releases, as *yy* releases are *snap*)

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/66509 .