# items dropped from Ubuntu when upgrading from 18.04 to 21.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 21.04.  There were a few in-use items which were not made available in Ubuntu 21.04 (and in Ubuntu 18.04, everything was working)

I have been running a package ("qnewb7" for Ubuntu) which required some packages which I can no longer locate and install.  These are:

```
   libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (and) ...
   32libz1  (replacement for "ia32-libs) (and)...
   libgtk2.0-0_i386
```

I keep getting told that ".deb" files are no longer usable, and the ".rpm" files that are (sometimes) shown?  I've no idea how to actually install these.  Always had great luck with .DEB.

Any idea where I can find and install these packages, or what packages will actually REPLACE them?

Without these, the software I'm using can not and will not work.

Comment: Were you using 32-bit Ubuntu while on 18.04? And how did you upgrade to 21.04?

Comment: .rpm is not an Ubuntu thing, that's Red Hat linux

Comment: Okay, I got the answer from "someone".  Tried the suggestions he offered and they worked...but I still can't get QNEWB7 to work again.  Stumped.  Tried contacting the software vendor but for some reason I can't get in to ask the questions.  Ive been using this company's software for the last 6 to 8 years or so...needless to say, there is no functioning "contact us" link on their site.  May have to dispose of ithe package and try something else.   THANKS MUCH FOR YOUR ASSISTANCE!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found some alternatives on 21.04:

For `libpng`, if the software really need version 12.0, there is a PPA by Linux Uprising that provides this.
[More on this here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/1476180)

The 32libz1 is replaced by a different package. It's `lib32z1` for 32-bit only, which is equivalent to the given package. If you need both 32bit and 64bit binaries, check out `zlib1g`. No version was given, so I can only provide the official repo packages.

`libgtk2.0-0` is still available in official repo, so just install as usual.

However, in the question, the first and last package are installed as i386 binaries, second one is not provided so I'll assume that it can be installed with normal package, but the other two need to have `:i386` suffix after the package name. For example:
`sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386`
And you have to add it after every packages that need to be installed as i386.