# Why Software updater wants to remove packages?

Tags: updates, update-manager

Ubuntu 21.10 Impish Indri 64-bit.
As in the title: why does software update wants to remove discord (I need it and installed it for a reason, duh) and libpng12-0 (which, I know, is outdated, but I do need THIS EXACT version).

And what's these: libc++1-12 and libc++1 I don't even know (perhaps some dependencies for libpng12-0).

So I am confused over here. What do I do in order to keep my stuff and run the update?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I see :-) sorry then.

Comment: 21.10 has libpng16-16! :~) I guess it is not happy about the 10 year old libpng you need.

Comment: SP Flash Tool (software for flashing firmware onto MTK devices) needs 12-0 for whatever reason. So I need it as it is. However I do understand that the thing is old and outdated. So what about discord? Why on god's green earth the updater would like to uninstall discord?! And how can I keep everything I intentionally installed? Please don't suggest to upgrade anyway and simply reinstall removed packages.

Comment: Packages are removed when their requirements and dependencies *conflict* with the rest of the system. It's that simple. Looks like your Discord deb was tied to a specific version of a dependency. If so, that's a bad idea...and you just found out why. The easy way to keep Discord in this sort of situation is to use the Snap instead of the deb.

Comment: For correct way on libpng12 installation see https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/66509 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to people in comments, I guess I got the answer:

@user535733:

> Looks like your Discord deb was tied to a specific version of a dependency. If so, that's a bad idea...and you just found out why. The easy way to keep Discord in this sort of situation is to use the Snap instead of the deb.

@N0rbert

> For correct way on libpng12 installation see [askubuntu.com/a/1194489/66509](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194489/66509)