# Unable to install "Screenlets" in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, screenlets

What I did to try to install screenlets:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:screenlets/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

The Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package screenlets
E: Unable to locate package screenlets-pack-all
```

Gnome Version: 3.36.3
Ubuntu Version: 20.04 LTS

Comment: You will need to ask the maintainer of the repository to fix his PPA.

Comment: I don't think screenlets will work with 20.04. It's very old widget software that hasn't been updated since 2010.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: Usually the method below is not recommended at all, but you can continue if you really want to get ScreenLets installed on your system.**

This method is an adaption of [method for 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194482/66509).

We need to add Ubuntu 16.04 LTS repositories to the system:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted
EOF
```

Then we need to install LibPNG 1.2 from [linuxuprising PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12) (as the regular deb-based method [does not work](https://askubuntu.com/q/1194386/66509)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/libpng12
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

Then we need to add [ScreenLets PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Escreenlets/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 94E58C34A8670E8C
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/screenlets/ppa/ubuntu xenial main"
```

And finally we will be allowed to install ScreenLets:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject python-gtk2
sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all
```

and enjoy.

To prevent possible problems with packages from 16.04 LTS you have to remove its repositories from the system with:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list 
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list.save
```

---

Note: just tested this method to install ScreenLets on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS. Not sure about GNOME Shell.

Comment: When I type the first command in it just shows a ">" symbol

Command Inserted: cat << EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial.list 

Output: ">"

Comment: First command is a single multi-line command. Copy it all - from `cat` to `EOF`, then paste.

Comment: I still get a ">" symbol as the OUTPUT

Comment: @N0rbert Although you certainly get a gold star for effort... I have to ask... why would you give instructions on how to install (hack in) OLD xenial software, and OLD 2010 screenlets, and a 3rd party PPA, on a 20.04 system? Never mind the OP is using GNOME, and you've only tested this on MATE. Why not just say, as I did, that screenlets isn't supported any more, and isn't compatible with 20.04? Much safer.

Comment: @heynnema I'm suggesting this because of some love to such great interesting traditional, but old software. The OP wants to install this application - I suggest the solution. It is 100% working, I have tested this method before posting. If it does not work on GNOME, it is a GNOME's problems. They break backward compatibility with traditional stuff. It is very easy to say that that the software is old and it will not work. But this is not my way. I hope that OP will learn how to copy and paste long commands and will get the ScreenLets software installed as the result.

Comment: @N0rbert I understand. However (and we've discussed this before... KeepNote...) when performing these kinds of hacks, the system can become very unreliable, and difficult to upgrade and support later.

Comment: I am waiting for this question to be solved. I have same situation. Screenlets is too good. Although I have move to Ubuntu 20.04 in the new laptop but I keep my old laptop just to make the Screenlets keep working on my 16.04. If there's alternative it would be good. I have try conky I think it's not as good as Screenlets